# Как добавить музыку в многооконое приложение?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Доброе время суток! Мне стало нужно добавить саундрек, но проблема в том, что приложение многооконное. Я посмотрел документации, видео о том как добавить музыку, но там объяснение с одним окном. Можете ли вы объяснить как сделать так, что бы по нажатию на кнопку воспроизводилась песня и перенеслось на другой экран, но что бы музыка продолжила играть, и прикратилась, когда пользователь нажмёт на кнопку, которая переносит на 3-ю страницу - прекращалась играть

Comment: Думаю сервис решит эту задачу https://metanit.com/java/android/16.1.php